# Libreoffice crash problem

Tags: libreoffice

So I have libreoffice 4.2.3.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 and when I have both writer and calc open and I want to drag and drop or just copy and paste a part of my table in the calc into my writer, they both will just crash.

What can I do to fix this? I am unable to continue my work because I cannot put the tables from calc into my writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also affects me, but I have a workaround. It only crashes when cells containing formulas are copied/pasted, so you can copy and paste values the cells of interest to another location in calc (i.e. Edit:"paste special" and uncheck "paste all" and "formulas" and check "Numbers"). Then the table can be copied and pasted into writer.

Comment: Will give this a try meanwhile I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This might be about to be fixed now. At [bug #1495097](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1495097) you find a link to a PPA with a version of *libhunspell-1.3-0* which fixes similar crashes in 14.04.